# VBA Evaluate 'IF' with 'OR' returns wrong values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula, evaluate

I have these columns:

[image: Columns]

I'm trying to evaluate them, this way:

```
dim myArray as variant

myArray = filter(application.transpose(columnSheet.evaluate("IF(OR(D=""D1"",D=""D2""),S,false)")),false,false)
```

Seeing that **"DISPENSER"** entire column name equals **"D"** and **"SELLER"** entire column name equals **"S"** and **"columnSheet"** is the name of **sheet object** where these columns supposed to be.

Filter application is due to feed "myArray" with the true results.

The problem is that **when I use "OR"** statement in the function that it's being **evaluating**, **I get "SELLER" *entire column* as result**. And if you try to apply the same function formula directly in sheet its returns the right results.

[image: Evaluate Function Formula Apply]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is with OR, but you can re-jig the IF to get the result you want:

```
myArray = Filter(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("IF(D=""D1"",S,if(D=""D2"",S,false))")), False, False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, buddy! I believe that's not the solution what I was looking for. But I did a workaround using a loop through every critearia and joined all filter results. I guess it was the best pratice to this case, because if I had criterias enough to pass a 255 characters formula, evaluate would return an error.